# Does a Curse card count as a Victory card when playing the Bureaucrat?

Tags: dominion

If I play a Bureaucrat and my opponent reveals a hand with a Curse card, does that Curse card go back on top of his/her deck?  Or does it not count as a "Victory card"?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No.  Curse cards do not have the type **Victory**.  They just have type **Curse**.

(You can see this in the rules or by reading the card closely - although they affect your VP total, they do not have "Victory" in the type line, just "Curse").

Answer (score 11):

**No**,

On page 2-3 of the [rules](http://www.riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_278_gameRules.pdf) you'll see the various types of cards.

- Treasure
- Victory

  - Estates
  - Duchies
  - Provinces
- Curse
- Randomizer
- Trash
- Kingdom

**Curse** is it's own type of card and not a **Victory** card.  On page 2, the explanation of the Curse card includes "card type, (curse, purple)